# what is the "jumpedToEnd" argument in the done or always option of jQuery animate?

Tags: jquery

i encountered to an unknown argument of **"done"** function and i noticed it's also repeated in **always** function  when i was reading [jQuery animate Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) :

> done
>
> Type: Function( Promise animation, Boolean **jumpedToEnd** )

or

> always
>
> Type: Function( Promise animation, Boolean **jumpedToEnd** )

is there anyone who knows what is the "jumpedToEnd" boolean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An auxiliary parameter for easier understanding. Like the remainingMs by the progress() command on the same Page. Boolean can only be true or false.

**If an animation is interrupted or unsuccessful, it automatically jump to the end.**